# GADNativeExpressAdView is not getting selected in uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When i tap on `UITableViewCell` it gets selected, but not opening the browser.

```
           cell = UITableViewCell(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  self.tableView.bounds.width, height: 90))
            let nativeExpressAdView = GADNativeExpressAdView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.width, height: 90))
            nativeExpressAdView.adUnitID = "adunitid"
            nativeExpressAdView.rootViewController = self

            let request = GADRequest()
            //request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
                nativeExpressAdView.loadRequest(request)
            })

            cell.selectionStyle = .None
            cell.backgroundView = nativeExpressAdView
```

When i click to GADNativeExpressAdView it isn not reversed to app store

[image]

Comment: Please make sure this that you write the code of opening the browser in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath not code.. I select in tablecell  GADNativeExpressAdView row it not open play store

Comment: Not getting what you want exactly, please elaborate properly.

Comment: thanks for help change cell.backgroundView (cell.contentView.addSubview(nativeExpressAdView))